# Is there a tool for windows 7 that provides an additional quick access bar

Tags: windows

Preferably a bar always on top that you can put your shortcuts at for quick access.
I have problems adding my shortcuts to the taskbar and even the start menu.
And the start menu is not convenient as you always have to open the start menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at something like [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/) which I believe you can set up with common programs and (if I'm remembering rightly) jump-out folder lists.

But then I could be getting it mixed up with [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/) which I know has an addon for big folder views type stuff called [Stack Docklet](http://rocketdock.com/addon/docklets/30962).  You could put all your shortcuts into a folder then point that docklet at that folder...

Answer (score 1):

If you liked the old Quick Launch area, you can use the Free Launch Bar (after installing, it is enabled/disabled by right-clicking the taskbar>Toobars:

http://www.freelaunchbar.com/

As you can see, after unlocking my taskbar, I was able to freely move it to the top of my screen. To the left are my many Quick Launch icons.

[image]